# Fetching data from remote API

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, openstack

I'm looking for some insight. I'm working on a project to format data into a nice readable format. Specifically the API calls are to Openstack from my ReactApp.

My main issue that stopping me from finishing this is the fact that the Openstack API doesn't have any headers configured on the Apache server the endpoints are hosted from. So of couse making the fetch request from my WebApp will be blocked due to my app not being in the same origin.

They are not my servers so I can't make any changes to them and the process to get the engineers who manage them to make this change is daunting.

My question is there a better way to get this done? I haven't found any libraries within node that allow me to send request with a flag to ignore certs, and then maybe I can install an extension on my browser to ignore cors. I have also tried that as the fix but I need to send post request to the Openstack instance and that requires sending body data in the request for authentication.

Should I be going through a backend that I can setup on a server to make curl requests so I can use the -k (ignore certs flag) to be able to store the data there then grab the data from there instead of the Openstack API? If this is a better scenario for my situation, anyone have recommended libraries to use?